# No logro entender clases y objetos en java

Tags: java

Me mandaron a hacer un ejercicio en el que se compararan los precios de dos panaderías, una que vendiera el pan por pieza en bolívares y otra que vendiera en dólares el kg de pan y comparar cuál de las dos tiene menor precio o si tienen el mismo.

El ejercicio tiene que hacerse usando clases y objetos pero como no entiendo y no sabía por donde entrarle decidí hacerlo sin el uso de las clases y objetos sino como de manera básica sin nada de eso. He investigado y leído mucho pero siguen habiendo conceptos que no entiendo y cosas que no sé cómo hacer: no sé cómo hacer un objeto en el que las variables que estén en él no sean definidas por mí sino por lo que ingrese el usuario.

Dejaré lo que yo hice aquí en caso de que alguien me pueda orientar en cómo agregar las clases y objetos a ese código o hacerlo de nuevo con eso:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("En la panaderia 'La doñita' se vende el pan por pieza con un costo de 0,5bs c/u");
     System.out.println("mientras que en la panaderia 'La fina' se vende el pan en $/kg con un costo de 2.15$/kg\n");
     
     System.out.println("Este programa lo ayudara a comparar los precios entre panaderias");
     System.out.println("teniendo en cuenta que cada pan pesa 0.09 kg (90gr) en ambos sitios\n");
     
     
  System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de piezas de pan que desea comprar");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int piezaspan = sc.nextInt();
  double preciopieza = 0.5;
  double pagototaldoñita = preciopieza*piezaspan;
  System.out.println("El total de bs a pagar en la panaderia 'La doñita' es de "+pagototaldoñita+"bs\n\n");
  
  System.out.println("Ingrese a que tasa (bs) reciben el dolar en 'La fina'");
  double tasadolar = sc.nextDouble();
  double preciodolarporkg = 2.15;//precio en dolares del kg de pan
  double pesodelpan = 0.09; //peso del pan en kg
  double pagototalfina = (piezaspan * 0.09) * preciodolarporkg;
  pagototalfina = Math.round(pagototalfina*100)/100d;
  double pagofinaenbs = pagototalfina*tasadolar;
  pagofinaenbs = Math.round(pagofinaenbs*100)/100d;
  System.out.println("El total a pagar por la misma cantidad de panes en 'La fina' es de "+ pagototalfina+"$, que equivalen a "+pagofinaenbs+"bs\n");
  
  
  System.out.println("Si comparamos ambos precios en bs segun la tasa indicada podemos ver que");
  
  if(pagofinaenbs>pagototaldoñita) {
     System.out.println("la panaderia que vende por pieza (La doñita) tiene menor precio que la que vende en $/kg (La fina)");
  }
  if(pagofinaenbs<pagototaldoñita){
  System.out.println("la panaderia que vende en $/kg (La fina) tiene menor precio que la que vende por pieza (La doñita)");    
  }
  if(pagofinaenbs==pagototaldoñita){
  System.out.println("Los precios en ambas panaderias son iguales");    
  }
  
  
 }
}
```

Entre sus explicaciones y más videos y más ejemplos que vi logré hacer este código, lo ejecuté y todo va bien pero siendo sincera más de la mitad de lo que hice no entiendo, ni el porqué, pero me guíe del ejemplo y funciona hasta ahora; más específicamente no entiendo qué vendría siendo la parte donde coloque `public void`, y allí en cada uno realice los distintos cálculos que necesitaba y después hice `public double` para lo que yo supongo devolver el valor del resultado de la operación que hice. El `public void` que nombré como comparaciondepanaderias al final de esa parte que contiene las 3 variables en las cuales se guardo el resultado de los procesos realmente no sé qué es ni por qué debía hacerse, pero seguí el ejemplo al igual que después lo volví a utilizar, y dentro de sus llaves coloqué todo lo que se mostraría en pantalla sobre los resultados y al final coloqué un `sc.close` que tampoco sé bien porque fue tal vez solo es para dar por terminado la lectura de datos en el programa, pero no estoy segura de nada.
En la parte del condicional `if` para acceder a los valores que quería comparar escribí `panaderia1.get` seguido del nombre de la variable, pero no estaba segura si era `get` o `set` o simplemente el nombre de la variable, solo justo como había hecho en el código anterior.

Realmente traté de entender el porqué de cada cosa que hacía pero hay unas que simplemente no les encontré sentido, sin embargo, como los ejemplos daban buenos resultados, hice lo mismo que vi en ellos. Si tuvieran el tiempo de revisar mi nuevo código y poder aclarar algunas de mis dudas se los agradecería enormemente.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Panaderia{
    int piezaspan;
    double preciopieza = 0.5;
    double pagototaldoñita;
    
    double tasadolar;
    double preciodolarporkg=2.15;
    double pesodelpan=0.09;
    double pagototalfina;
    double pagofinaenbs;
    public void setpagototaldoñita() {
    pagototaldoñita = piezaspan * preciopieza;
    }

    public void setpagototalfina() {
    pagototalfina = (piezaspan * 0.09) * preciodolarporkg;
 pagototalfina = Math.round(pagototalfina*100)/100d;
    }
    
    public void setpagofinaenbs(){
    pagofinaenbs = pagototalfina*tasadolar;
 pagofinaenbs = Math.round(pagofinaenbs*100)/100d;
    }
    
    public double getpagototaldoñita() {
    return pagototaldoñita;
  }
    
    public double getpagototalfina(){
    return pagototalfina;
    }  
    
    public double getpagofinaenbs(){
    return pagofinaenbs;    
        
   }
   
   public void comparaciondepanaderias() {
    setpagototaldoñita();
    setpagototalfina();
    setpagofinaenbs();
  }
  
    
}
public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Panaderia panaderia1 = new Panaderia();//llamando al objeto de tipo panaderia 
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("En la panaderia 'La doñita' se vende el pan por pieza con un costo de 0,5bs c/u");
     System.out.println("mientras que en la panaderia 'La fina' se vende el pan en $/kg con un costo de 2.15$/kg\n");
   
     System.out.println("Este programa lo ayudara a comparar los precios entre panaderias");
     System.out.println("teniendo en cuenta que cada pan pesa 0.09 kg (90gr) aprox. en ambos sitios\n");
     
     
  System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de piezas de pan que desea comprar");
  panaderia1.piezaspan = sc.nextInt();
  
  System.out.println("Ingrese a que tasa (bs) reciben el dolar en 'La fina'");
  panaderia1.tasadolar = sc.nextDouble();
  
  panaderia1.comparaciondepanaderias();
  
  System.out.println("\n\nEl total de bs a pagar en la panaderia 'La doñita' es de "+panaderia1.getpagototaldoñita()+"bs");
  System.out.println("mientras que el total a pagar por la misma cantidad de panes en 'La fina' es de "+ panaderia1.getpagototalfina()+"$, que equivalen a "+panaderia1.getpagofinaenbs()+"bs\n");
  System.out.println("Si comparamos ambos precios en bs segun la tasa indicada podemos ver que");
  
  if(panaderia1.getpagofinaenbs()>panaderia1.getpagototaldoñita()) {
     System.out.println("la panaderia que vende por pieza (La doñita) tiene menor precio que la que vende en $/kg (La fina)");
  }
  if(panaderia1.getpagofinaenbs()<panaderia1.getpagototaldoñita()){
  System.out.println("la panaderia que vende en $/kg (La fina) tiene menor precio que la que vende por pieza (La doñita)");    
  }
  if(panaderia1.getpagofinaenbs()==panaderia1.getpagototaldoñita()){
  System.out.println("Los precios en ambas panaderias son iguales");    
  }
  
  
  sc.close();
  
 }
}
```

Comment: Pues precisamente la Programación Orientada a Objetos existe para simplificar el dilema y el lío que te estás haciendo aquí. Sería cuestión de crear una clase llamada `Panadería`  donde reflejas toda la lógica según la cual operan las panaderías para tu caso: ¿vende en dólares o en bolívares?, ¿vende en kg o por piezas? La clase deberá tener también un método `vender`, para que le puedas pedir pan, y metes dentro lógica para ir computando el pan que se venda ... y otro método `totalVendido` donde obtendrás la cantidad que vendió esa instancia del objeto. Tu principal error ...

Comment: ... ha sido precisamente no haber modelado tu clase `Panaderia` ... y todas tus penas vienen de ahí. Entonces, te invito a empezar por ahí, intenta crear una clase `Panaderia` donde reflejes toda la lógica. Eso te ayudará a entender los objetos y verás lo fácil que será todo luego. Si tienes algún problema con la clase te ayudaremos, o si hay cosas que se pueden mejorar te lo diremos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer y responder . Estuve intentando hacer una clase con el nombre panaderia pero todo lo que he visto de ejemplos y explicaciones de clases y objetos el programador le da unos valores determinados a los objetos y eso me confunde porque tengo muchos datos que el usuario debe ingresar. Cuando usted dice que refleje toda la lógica exactamente a que se refiere?

Comment: No sé si sea difícil explicarlo pero para mí si lo es. Te sugiero que busques algunos videos o algún artículo, preferentemente en Java porque podría confundirte si está hecho en base a otro lenguaje. Quizás está explicación de la documentación de Java te ayude: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! lee sobre propiedades de las clases... tu programa ya usa un monton de clases... las clases tiene variables, iguales a las variables que declaras en tu main (que es un metodo dentro de una clase) y esas variables (propiedades) pueden tomar los valores que vos quieras (como cualquier variable) tal vez te confunden los getters y setters?

Comment: Mira, principalmente si has visto otros lenguajes de programación, puedes relacionarlos con las funciones, en java se llaman métodos pero por ejemplo en c++ se le suele decir funciones miembro, entonces, lo que tienes que poner dentro de los métodos es el funcionamiento de tu programa, y posteriormente hacer el llamado de esas funciones dentro del ```main```, como dices para pasar los valores de variables a los métodos, tienes que crear los objetos de tu clase al igual que haces por ejemplo como con el ``` scanner```, luego le pasas el valor de dicha variable como parámetro al llamado del méto

Comment: Edite la pregunta para que pudieran ver el nuevo código que hice usando las clases y objetos, espero sus comentarios y correcciones cuando les sea posible revisarlo.